# Perform Percentage Calculation in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I try to do the sum by group and calculate how many percent each group account for. It is easy to do the `SUMIF` using the `GROUP BY` but then I stuck at `SUM (ALL)` - I guess I could try to do `SUM(CASE IF GROUP='A' THEN END) + SUM(CASE IF GROUP='B'...` but then whatif there is more GROUP `:(`

`SELECT GROUP, SUM(SALES), SUM(SALES)/TOTAL FROM DATABASE.SALETABLE`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUM ... OVER()` to get the total sales.

```
SELECT [Group],
       SUM(SALES) AS [Sales],
       100.0 * SUM(SALES) / SUM(SUM(SALES)) OVER () AS [%]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [Group]
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c330/1)

Comment: I just figured it out - using `SUM(SALES)/(SELECT SUM(SALES)`

Comment: thanks, it does not allow me to accept as solution immediately that why